# Does integrating WebRTC one to one audio/video calls affect the performance of web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, webrtc

After knowing about some great features of WebRTC, I thought of using WebRTC one to one audio/video calls in my web application. The web application is for many organizations/entities of a category who can register and keep recording several records daily for their internal working and about their clients. The clients of these individual organizations/entities also have access to the web application to access their details.

The purpose of using WebRTC is for communication between clients and organizations. Also for daily inquires by new people to these organizations about products and services.

While going through articles on google etc. I found broadcasting or one to many calls requires very high bandwidth to users if we don't make use of Media Server.

So what is the case for one to one calls?
Will it affect the performance of web application or bring any critical situation if several users are making audio/video calls(one to one) to each other simultaneously as a routine?

The number of users will be very large and users will be recording daily several entries as their routine work. But still it is manageable and application will be running smoothly but I am not sure about the new concept WebRTC. Will it require a very high hosting plan? Is using WebRTC for current scenario suitable or advisable?

Answer (score 3):

WebRTC by its nature is Peer-to-Peer. Meaning that the streaming data is handled CLIENT side. All decoding, encoding, ICE candidate gathering/negotiation, and media encrypting/transmitting will happen on the client side and not on server side. So, you will be providing the pages, client side JS, and some data exchange(session negotiation signalling) but all in all, it is not a huge amount of work. It should be easily handled without having to worry about your host machine being over worked.

All that said, here are the only a performance concerns that would **POSSIBLY** affect your hosting server.

1. Signalling session startup, negotiations, and tare down. This is very minimal(only some json data at the beginning of a session). This should not be too much of a burden but you should be aware that if 1000 sessions start at the same time, you will have a queue of messages to direct to the needed parties. How you determine the parties, forward the messages, and what work you do server side could all affect performance. If written smartly(how to store sessions, how to forward messages, etc.) should not be a terrible burden.This could easily done with [SignalR](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/48/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-SignalR.aspx) since you are on ASP.NET or you could use a separate one running Node.js(or the same box, does not matter) if you so desired.
2. RTP TURN relay if needed. This will probably be through a different server(or the same one as your hosting server if you want). For SOME connections, a TURN server is needed and any production ready WebRTC solution should take this into account. [Here is a good open source turn server](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/). Bandwidth usage here could be very high as RTP packets are sent to this server and the forwarded to the peer in the connection.
3. If you are recording the streams, you may have increased hosting traffic depending on how you implement it. Firefox supports [client side recording](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API) of the streams but Chrome does not(they say it is in the works currently). You could use [existing JS libraries](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) to record the feeds client side and then push them anywhere you want. You could also push all the data through a MediaServer that will mux, demux, and forward the data to be recorded anywhere you like. [Janus-Gateway videoroom](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/) is a good lightweight example of a mediaserver.

Client side is a different story.

1. There are higher level concerns in the Javascript. If you use one of the recording JS libraries, this is especially evident as they do canvas captures numerous times a second which are a heavy hit and would degrade the user experience.
2. CPU utilization by the browser will increase as the quality of the video being streamed increases. This is rather obvious as HD video frames take more CPU power to encode/decode than SD frames.
3. Client side bandwidth usage can also be an issue. Chrome and Firefox try to modify the bitrate of each video/audio feed dynamically but the video Bitrate can go all the way up to 2 Mbps. You can cap this in Chrome( by adding an attribute in the SDP) but not in Firefox(last I checked) as of yet.